# Neo4j bloom displays the ID, not the primary property of my node for one specific label

Tags: neo4j, label, graph-databases

I think this is because it's displaying the label as "other" despite the fact that it's already labeled as "treatment"

[image]
[image]

The weird thing is it works perfectly in the neo4j browser!!

[image]

Also, when I go to create a node in neo4j bloom, "treatment" is absent from node labels!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nvm, figured this out

you have to click the slidey thing in the top left so it displays this:

[image]

Then scroll to the bottom and click "add category"

[image]

and you'll see categories you've made that for whatever reason haven't been added to bloom

[image]